# Selenium Python: Trying to get an iframe within an iframe

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

I'm trying to switch the Selenium 'focus' to the contents inside of an iframe that's inside of another iframe. My selenium test below seems to work so far. However, there is another iframe within that iframe that I want to get- but I'm not sure now.

Here is the markup (second iframe highlighted):

[image]

This is my test so far (which works- just not sure how to get the second iframe within the first iframe):

```
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from .functional_test import FunctionalTest


class MyTest(FunctionalTest):
    URL = '/datastory/my-datastory/'


    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        """Set up method."""
        super().setUpClass()

        cls.URL = cls.format_url(cls.URL)
        cls.login_user(cls)

    def test_iframe(self):
        container = self.browser.find_element_by_id('visual-31')
        carousel = container.find_element_by_css_selector('.col-sm-12:nth-child(2) div.visual #classics-50-carousel')
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 60)
        wait.until(ec.visibility_of(carousel))
        page_source = carousel.get_attribute("src");
        self.assertEqual(
            page_source,
            'https://observablehq.com/embed/@ddsg/paramount-databyte-visuals?cells=classics50yrs'
        )
        # switch Selenium focus to the iframe
        iframe = self.browser.switch_to.frame(carousel);
        #NOW HOW DO I GET THE OTHER IFRAME??
        # switch back
        self.browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: you'd use the same method, (once you've switched to the parent frame) though I'd use the "frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt" expected condition for both.  You could target the src attribute when you locate it: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To switch within nested *`<iframe>`* elements so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the **parent** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the **child** *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Then `driver.find_element()`
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://xyz/datastory/my-datastory/')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.content[src='https://observablehq.com/embed/@ddsg/paramount-databyte-visuals?cells=classics50yrs']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe.content[src*='observableusercontent']")))
    element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "id")
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get('https://xyz/datastory/my-datastory/')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@class='content' and @src='https://observablehq.com/embed/@ddsg/paramount-databyte-visuals?cells=classics50yrs']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'observableusercontent')]")))
    element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "id")
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)